# Finding orthogonal trajectories of $y = cx^2$, Problem 3.1.b in Simmons Differential Equations with Historical Notes

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I just got Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes and worked through the Problems in Section 3.
The solution to one of the problems I do not quite get (I know it's no different from mine, but I can't figure out how they computed it that way)

The problem;
Find the orthogonal trajectories of:

1b. $y = cx^2$

my attempt went as follows:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2cx$$
$$-\frac{dx}{dy}=2cx$$
Substituting c.
$$-\frac{dx}{dy}= 2x\frac{y}{x^2}=\frac{2y}{x}$$
$$-x{dx}={2y}{dy}$$
I integrate both sides and get
$$\frac{-x^2}{2} + c = \frac{2y^2}{2}= y^2$$
Moving the terms around I get:
$$x^2 + 2y^2 = c$$

The solution is $x^2 + 2y^2= c^2$
I do understand that c is just a constant and arbitrary so c^2 isn't much different from c.
But I am afraid that I may have missed something or made an error to arrive at this solution because I can't figure out how the c squared term was computed.
Can someone point out my mistake here?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Your constant of integration $c$ and $c$ from $y=cx^2$, are they same? Why?

Comment: @cosmo5 thank you. I did not think that they are the same, because the original is a constant describing a particular function in the family and the other is the constant left from integration. But now that I think about it, they could be the same? Is that my mistake?

Comment: $c$  in $y=cx^2$, _as a parameter_, describes one family of curves. What you have obtained is a different family of curves, namely orthogonal to previous one. It needs a different parameter.

Comment: @cosmo5 thank you very much, for some of my tries I did actually use different parameters. I still don't seem to understand the solution in the book though then. Where does the $c^2$ term come from? Can I get it from the other parameter say, k?

Comment: @cosmo5 Oh, I think I got it, substituting from the original equation again on the right side and eliminating could this be it? I.e. the correct way to go about it? Sorry to be a pain.

Comment: Hello, I had to go away from pc. Your solution is correct as $x^2+2y^2=K$. I think the book has just used same letter $c$.

Comment: @cosmo5 thank you! I think that too now. Could it be then, that they square their c is also just quite arbitrary like my original intuition? Maybe to make the equation look more pretty or in line with ellipse equations?

Comment: I can explain why they wrote it instead as $K^2$, because LHS is never negative. This then becomes equation of ellipses with semi-axes of length $\sqrt K$ and $\sqrt (K/2)$. Check out standard equation of ellipse here : [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse)

Comment: @cosmo5 thank you so much, it is clear now! I am so sorry to take up so much of your time. I hope to pay it forward someday.

Comment: Not at all, welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have eliminated $c$ in the fourth step to get the ODE for the orthogonal trajectories. Finally, in solving the last ODE you cannot use the same constan $c$. Use spmething else like $k$. So the  $x^2+2y^2=k$ are the orthogoalal family of curves to the family $y=cx^2$. Thse two together present an orthogonal system ehere any point in the plane can be assigned copoordonates $(c,k)$ or $(k,c)$.

The method id by differentiation you eliminate the constant from the eqn. of the curve and set up the ODE. Then change $y' \to -1/y'$, set up second ODE, solve this and introduce a new constant.

In the fig. below,  See the  curves and the orthogonal curves for $c=\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3$ and $k=1,2,3,4$, whereever they cut the cut each other orthogonally.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and help. 
From the discussion with cosmo5, I have also used a different parameter after integration before. I can see how that makes sense to keep them seperated. Yet in the official solution then, I suspect $c^2$ refers to the original c. I still don't see how Simmons arrived there? Apologies for being a bit slow here and thank you again.

Comment: Oh, could it be substituting once more from the original equation? I think I can work it out this way.

Comment: No,  it may work only accidentally. Read my answer I have added a few more lines and a figure. You may work out another problem when $y=cx$ the orthogonal trajectories you get are $x^2+y^2=k, k>0$

Comment: Thank you. I think in the book they use c for both parameters it seems. This illustration has been very helpful. I do understand this concept and I also did the graph. I am so very sorry, the official solution still eludes me. 
How did they arrive at $x^2 + 2y^2 = c^2$ as the solution for the family of curves of the orthogonal trajectories?
Also, assuming I have understood all you have explained to me, their c, is our k, is this correct?